# Tix package (.deb) installed, Tcl doesn't see it

Tags: debian, apt, tcl

I'm on Debian Sid, I have installed the `tix` package (as in `sudo apt install tix`) and later I've tried to load it, as in

```
$ tclsh
% package require Tk
8.6.8
% package require Tix
can't find package Tix
% ^D
$
```

Am I missing something obvious or should I file a bug report?

---

This is the status of the relevant packages at the moment of writing

```
$ dpkg -l tcl tk tix
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=============================================
ii  tcl            8.6.9+1      amd64        Tool Command Language (default version) - she
ii  tix            8.4.3-10     amd64        library for Tk -- runtime package
ii  tk             8.6.9+1      amd64        Toolkit for Tcl and X11 (default version) - w
```

Comment: Hmm.. shouldn't the version number reported by `package require Tk` be the same as the `tk` package version reported by `dpkg`? Do you have a non-default installation of tcl/tk on your system as well (in home or usr/local)? What does `set auto_path` say (in the tclsh)?

Comment: On Buster, I get `% package require Tix
NULL main window`. I get the same versions for `dpkg -l tcl tk tix` as you do.